# Couldn't transpose numpy 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

Couldn't transpose np.array

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))

print(arr)
arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)
print('------------')
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]]

 [[ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]]
------------
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]]

 [[ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]]
```

I think that's weird. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/734lcl/complicated_numpy_transpose_question/) the same example but it works. `numpy==1.17.2` What could be wrong?

Comment: It's not in-place. So, assign it to a new variable and then check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing 'arr = arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)' in place of 'arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)'. You can also try typing 'print(arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)' in place of 'print(arr)'.

Comment: I just ran it on a Jupyter notebook by changing 'arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)' to 'arr = arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)'. It worked.